# Force navigator to Open Link in New Tab by URL

Tags: html

i have a request if possible,
 i have an interface which containts a table :

```
name of application   url 
XXXXXX                www.xxx.com
```

Problem is when I click in the url I lose my information on my current page. 
my question is  there is a code language  by Internet explorer FF chrome... provide this action 
open in tab this url   to put in the url  like  the method version and the other
like this  about:version ==> open in new tab : this url   to put in the url navigator 
and we get a new tab 
thank you for help .
i try open in a new tab by tools provided by IE , but if  possible provide a solution like a code entered in url to open a new tab

Comment: if there a code in navigator like open in new tab : url

Answer (score 12):

If I get you, you want your link to open the page in another tab.

You may use the **target** attribute of the link like this :

```
<a href="somepage.html" target=newtab>text</a>
```

If you want something you can type in the URL field of the browser, that is a `bookmarklet,` you may use this :

```
javascript: window.open('http://www.dystroy.org');
```

In most browsers, ctrl-click a link do the same thing.

EDIT :

If what you can modify is only the `href` attribute of the link, you can make this href be like this :

```
 <a href="javascript:window.open('http://www.dystroy.org');" target=_blank>text</a>
```

Comment: thank you , but whant i want not a code in html a code in url navigator   :D

Comment: like this open new tab: url  , is there this option ??

Comment: dystroy ,  i cant modify the code , what i can modify is the url in the table only :( and the paramter is check , there is a code to add before url in the table to open a new tab ??

Comment: `target=newtab` cool new thing I learned today!! thanks, a +3 for you :-) (+2 done on some of your today's accepted answers)

Comment: @Nelson : please don't upvote other answers without reading it and being sure they deserve it.

Comment: @dystroy, have you any solution please for this question :D

Comment: from where does the newtab comes from? I do not think it opens a newtab? It must be trying to locate a frameset named 'newtab'? _blank on the other hand will open either a new window or tab

Comment: @HatimHeffoudhi I edited with a suggestion but I'm really not sure I understand your problem.

Comment: @dystroy , what i want to ask ,imagine you have an input in your page  you dont have any information what is behind the page the code the parametre just the input and  you can put a url in it , like this www.google.com and  after you have this url in the next page to be clicked , and when you click on, you see the page in the tab.         is there a commande like this  openinnewtab:"http://www.google.com"

Comment: Why can't you use `window.open(url)` ?

Comment: in a url definition ??? i cant put a javascript in a url definition but if there a method proposed by ie and ff to put in the url ?? dystroy  is there a method in the bar navigator to entered like open_new_tab: www.google.com  by code navigator not in javascript or html

Comment: could any one tell me if i sent URL to my page to some one how can make this link open in same tab not new tab html ?

Comment: @IslamEl-shazly You can't do that with just an URL.

Answer (score 2):

If its a hyperlink just add a "target" to the hyperlink with its value as "_blank". Working example:

```
<a id="termsLink" href="www.someLink.com" target=_blank>
                Terms and Conditions</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The java script solution works great in case of shortcodes which offer you an href (or url) option but no target parameter. Here is an example with a popular callout shortcode:

```
[callout title='Your big Title' text='your small text...' button_text='CLICK ME' button link="**javascript:window.open**('http://www.dystroy.org');"]
```

Without the javascript, the linked page would open onto the current one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any code to open a link in a new tab or window. HTML already has that functionality built in.

Use an  tag to show your url and use the target attribute to tell it to open in a new window.

Example:

```
<a href="http://www.xxx.com" target="_blank">www.xxx.com</a>
```

Learn more about a tag and target attribute [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

Comment: buddhi ,  i cant modify the code , what i can modify is the url in the table only :( and  the paramter is check , there is a code to add before url in the table to open a new tab ??

Comment: Can you at least add some client side javascript? Can you post how the HTML looks like for your table? (Not the database table, but the table on the interface, I assume its a HTML table)

Comment: no i cant modify  the code :( not for javascript not for html , so want can i do is just  modifye the url , and if possible inside this url add a thing or a code for can ie or ff open it in a new tab

Comment: Please post how the HTML looks like in the final page, or send us a link where we can see the page.

Comment: its a intranet, the team blocked any request from other site ,that why we cant modidy the html  :c

Comment: I'm not asking you to modify it. Just show it to us, so we can see if you can modify your "table" to get what you want done.

Comment: i can't modify the table , because we dont have the rule or the permissions to modify  anything in the intranet , the only thing i can do is change the text of url entered like a command plus url , a command which create a new tab and put the url in it . than kou buddhi for your help